# function holding old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding a `Item` Component in the list when user click on `Add Item` button. I am passing a `removeItem` function to the `Item` component, so when user clicks on the `Cancel` button then i can remove that particular `Item` component from list. But the problem is when i use `removeItem` function and check the `items.length` it does not show the exact `items` length. Suppose i added four Items and i click on the most bottom item then it will show `0` length, if i click on second last then it will show `1` length. But what i want it must show  `4` length.

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./App.module.css";

const DUMMY_DATA = [];

function App() {
  const [items, setItem] = useState(DUMMY_DATA);

  function removeItem() {
    console.log(items.length);
  }

  function addNewItem() {
    setItem((prevItems) => {
      return [
        <Item key={Math.random()} cancelItem={removeItem} />,
        ...prevItems,
      ];
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addNewItem}>Add New Item</button>
      {items.map((item) => item)}
    </div>
  );
}

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
      <button onClick={props.cancelItem}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happen because when you add your item component to the list, it save the actual length of item that why you see in each component different length.
so instead try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./App.module.css";

const DUMMY_DATA = [];

function App() {
  const [items, setItem] = useState(DUMMY_DATA);

  function removeItem() {
    console.log(items.length);
  }

  function addNewItem() {
    setItem((prevItems) =>[...prvItems,{id:Math.random()}])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addNewItem}>Add New Item</button>
      {items.map((item) => <Item key={item.id} cancelItem={removeItem} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="" id="" />
      <button onClick={props.cancelItem}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```